# Сортировка по текстовой дате

Tags: sql

Есть простой запрос:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY day DESC
```

По дню сортируется отлично. Нужно, чтобы внутри дня сортировка шла и по времени. Но время записано в виде `14-20` - обычное текстовое поле.
Пытаюсь что-то такое сделать:

```
(SELECT * FROM table) UNION (SELECT time = CONVERT(VARCHAR, CONVERT(DATETIME, time, 103), 103) FROM table) ORDER BY data DESC, time DESC
```

Но вообще ничего не выходит.

Comment: А сделать поле полноценным `DATETIME`'ом/`TIME`'ом не вариант?

Comment: SELECT id,data,str_to_date(time, "%H-%i") myTime FROM `table` order by data desc, myTime desc

Comment: Спасибо! Все работает!